# Geodatabase to UML

Tags: enterprise-geodatabase, esri-geodatabase, uml

I want to convert geodatabase to the UML diagram in order to analyze the relations and the attribute of the gdb file.

Is there a method for this transformation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Esri [specifically recommends](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/manage-data/geodatabases/a-note-about-the-use-of-uml-for-geodatabase-design.htm) using third party software ([Enterprise Architect](https://sparxsystems.com/)) for UML design. You could also edit the Geodatabase XML directly in an XML editor, but this approach is not as human-readable.